# Android Galaxy S3 stopped mounting mtp to debian testing

Tags: android, debian, usb, libusb, mtp

So it used to just work.  Plug in the phone and folder pops open showing files.  Then one day it didn't.  That was about two months ago.  Most likely this is due to some update to debian.  I have reached a dead end trying to figure this out and need some help.

So now I plug in the phone and I see one or more of two different pop up message boxes with this text.

```
Unable to mount SAMSUNG Android SGH I747
Unable to open MTP device '[usb:001,040]'

Unable to mount SAMSUNG Android SGH I747
Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

[As an aside, colorization is all wrong in block above.  How do I stop this?]

I just installed the gmtp app from debian repo and it works, sometimes.
When I start gmtp from a shell it writes this text after I click on the "connect" button.

```
libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/002/003: Permission denied.
libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
```

Then after about 10 seconds (sometimes), gmtp connects and works with no further messages.  If gmtp doesn't work, then it hangs.  After you kill gmtp, it is necessary to reboot debian to get the phone to connect again.

When not using gmtp and I plug in the phone, I get this in dmesg:

```
[692137.131777] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 46 using ehci-pci
[692137.226717] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
[692137.226722] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[692137.226725] usb 1-1.1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android_SGH-I747
[692137.226727] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[692137.226729] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: ad1d8c01
```

Then the device shows up in nemo.  When I click on it to mount it there is this in dmesg:

```
[692156.903396] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 46
[692157.099945] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 47 using ehci-pci
[692157.171961] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[692157.347945] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[692157.523942] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 48 using ehci-pci
[692157.619139] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
[692157.619144] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[692157.619147] usb 1-1.1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android_SGH-I747
[692157.619149] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[692157.619151] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: ad1d8c01
[692180.636183] usb 1-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 48 using ehci-pci
[692180.730170] usb 1-1.1: usbfs: process 11924 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[692180.730258] usb 1-1.1: usbfs: process 11969 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[692180.804182] usb 1-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 48 using ehci-pci
[692180.898302] usb 1-1.1: usbfs: process 11969 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[692180.898403] usb 1-1.1: usbfs: process 11924 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
[692180.898794] usb 1-1.1: usbfs: process 11969 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me the output of this command `mtp-detect`

Answer (score 0):

Reason of this message `Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying` can be:::

1. Hardware Connectivity issue which can be because of either fault in port or cable. Try with different cable once because `usb 1-1.1: usbfs: process 11924 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use` comes when it's sort of about hardware.
2. MTP Library issue: Sometimes OS updates crashes with old mtp libs. Try `mv /usr/local/lib/libmtp.so.9 /usr/local/lib/libmtp.so.9_backUp`. Instead of removing we better keep it's backup so that if that doesn't work you can rollback this workaround. Renaming/removing lib in my case worked.